# How are functions inside controllers accesed in SocialEngine?

Tags: php, socialengine

For example I have edit profile page which have a form for editing the summary. the file's name is Index.tpl.
In form I have a text field, I have added the saveSummary() in the controller i.e. controller.php. How can I invoke the given function on clicking on submit button of form.

Answer (score 1):

Answering directly to your question, you should submit the form to `/save-summary/` action if it's called `saveSummary()` in your controller. Of course don't forget to include prefix of the route.

Generally your approach is not correct because you're trying to use different actions for displaying content and processing the form – you can easily do both operations in one action. Check for `isPost()` and `getPost()` in other controllers – this methods are used to divide parts of action responsible for simply getting and displaying content and for processing form data.

Answer (score 0):

You can access controller functions by using action handle at the end of function name ex -

```
class Mymodule_MytestController extends Core_Controller_Action_Standard{
    public function saveSummaryAction(){
   .......
    }
}
```

---